# How to configure Windows server WSUS server connection settings?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update

I know we have a custom WSUS server running in the intranet, how do I configure my Windows 2008 server installations to use that server for updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the GPO in which those computer accounts reside in Active Directory Users and Computers.

The setting is `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update.`

Change the "Specify Intranet Microsoft Update Service Location" value to `http://servername`

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the group policies to the servers that tell them where to get their updates from.